# How to filter detailTextLabel data using SearchBar in ios swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using SearchBar for filtering the contacts table.I am searching by using name field.Its filtering name but not the mobile number.How to filter mobile number also parallelly along with respective name in ios swift

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filtered = stringArray.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })

    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    self.myTable.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = myTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    if(searchActive){
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = numArray[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = stringArray[indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = numArray[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What's your code to filter the `name` property? Do a "or myNumber.something(withSearchText)"?

Comment: `cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]; cell.detailTextLabel?.text = numArray[indexPath.row]` Best tip: Don't use 2 arrays. Use only one. A Name + a Number are meant to be together. Use a single array that will hold a struct/dict/customObject that handles 2 properties name & number. Why sync' them? You are seeing this effect yourself, if you filter/remove one in one array, the other will be not sync'ed anymore.

Comment: Thanks for Your quick answer. I'm trying.

Comment: Can you please post some code how you filter and your data structure. I mean array or array of objects. @gopal